# Prolog | Return true if two elements in a 3x4 matrix are diagonal

Tags: matrix, prolog, diagonal

I'm just starting to learn prolog. I have a question where the object is a slot in a 3x4 matrix

```
a b c d 
e f g h
i j k l
```

Each element is a slot

```
Slot(Name,leftNeighbor,UpperNeighbor, RightNeighbor,LowerNeighbor).
```

I need to create a query called `diagonal(Name1,Name2)` that returns true if two slots are diagonal( example: `a,f,k` are diagonal, `d,j,g` are too).

I was thinking about checking for each element if his left/right neighbor's lower neighbor is the Name2, or if that element's own left/right neighbor's Lower neighbor is Name2. Is there a simpler way to find this? it looks too long and inefficient to me.

These are my current rules
~

```
slot(name,LeftNeighbor,UpperNeighbor,RightNeighbor,LowerNeighbor).
slot(a,none,none,b,e).
slot(b,a,none,c,f).
slot(c,b,none,d,g).
slot(d,c,none,none,h).
slot(e,none,a,f,i).
slot(f,e,b,g,j).
slot(g,f,c,h,k).
slot(h,g,d,none,l).
slot(i,none,e,j,none).
slot(j,i,f,k,none).
slot(k,j,g,l,none).
slot(l,k,h,none,none).
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have the correct idea. Two elements A and B are diagonal when the upper neighbour of A is the left neighbour of B; or the upper neighbor of A is the right neighbour of B; and so on. It isn't that inefficient. It takes one lookup to get the neighbours of A, and then one lookup to see what the neighbours of those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out a few days ago.

Here is the solution for all who may need it:

```
diag_1(Name1,Name2) :- slot(Name1,_,_,A,_), A \= none, slot(Name2,_,A,_,_). 
diag_1(Name1,Name2) :- slot(Name1,_,_,A,_), A \= none, slot(Name2,_,B,_,_), B \= none, diag_1(A,B).

diag_2(Name1,Name2) :- slot(Name1,_,_,_,A), A \= none, slot(Name2,_,_,A,_). %same on the other diagonal
diag_2(Name1,Name2) :- slot(Name1,_,_,_,A), A \= none, slot(Name2,_,_,B,_), B \= none, diag_2(A,B).

diagonal(Name1,Name2) :- diag_1(Name1,Name2) ; diag_1(Name2,Name1) ; diag_2(Name1,Name2) ; diag_2(Name2,Name1).
```